# Can't run newly created bot locally - Error reading bot file

Tags: javascript, botframework

I know that this question has been asked before, however, I did not find the solution applied by author suitable for me. Therefore I have to ask again. Sorry.

I have generated bot using Bot Builder SDK v4 and Yeoman following the steps, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

After answering a few simple questions, directory skeleton with files has been generated.

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       02/01/2019     16:58                cognitiveModels
d-----       02/01/2019     16:58                deploymentScripts
d-----       02/01/2019     16:58                dialogs
d-----       02/01/2019     16:59                node_modules
-a----       02/01/2019     17:21             47 .env
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58            313 .eslintrc.js
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58             22 .gitignore
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58          12042 bot.js
-a----       02/01/2019     17:12            682 dev-hr-app.bot
-a----       02/01/2019     17:28           5087 index.js
-a----       02/01/2019     16:59         210624 package-lock.json
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58           1179 package.json
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58           1600 PREREQUISITES.md
-a----       02/01/2019     16:58           3106 README.md
```

Now I'm trying to run bot locally so I can connect to it using bot framework emulator and I'm getting the following error:

```
> node ./index.js


Error reading bot file. Please ensure you have valid botFilePath and 
 botFileSecret set for your environment.

- The botFileSecret is available under appsettings for your Azure Bot 
  Service bot.

- If you are running this bot locally, consider adding a .env file with 
  botFilePath and botFileSecret.

- See https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot file its use 
  and bot configuration.
```

Here is the content of .env file:

```
botFilePath="./dev-hr-app.bot"
botFileSecret=""
```

Here is the content of my .bot file:

```
{
"name": "dev-hr-app",
"services": [
    {
        "type": "endpoint",
        "name": "development",
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
        "appId": "",
        "appPassword": "",
        "id": "1"
    }
    {
        "type": "luis",
        "name": "dev-hr-app",
        "appId": "<ID>", <- deleted
        "version": "0.1",
        "authoringKey": "<Key>", <- deleted
        "subscriptionKey": "<Key>", <- deleted
        "region": "westus",
        "id": "206"
    }
],
"padlock": "",
"version": "2.0"
```

}

And here is the content of my index.js file:

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

// index.js is used to setup and configure your bot

// Import required packages
// const env = require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});

const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services. See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, MemoryStorage, ConversationState, UserState } = require('botbuilder');
// Import required bot configuration.
const { BotConfiguration } = require('botframework-config');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { BasicBot } = require('./bot');

// Read botFilePath and botFileSecret from .env file
// Note: Ensure you have a .env file and include botFilePath and botFileSecret.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Get the .bot file path
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot file its use and bot configuration.
const BOT_FILE = path.join(__dirname, (process.env.botFilePath || ''));
let botConfig;
try {
    // Read bot configuration from .bot file.
    botConfig = BotConfiguration.loadSync(BOT_FILE, process.env.botFileSecret);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`\nError reading bot file. Please ensure you have valid botFilePath and botFileSecret set for your environment.`);
    console.error(`\n - The botFileSecret is available under appsettings for your Azure Bot Service bot.`);
    console.error(`\n - If you are running this bot locally, consider adding a .env file with botFilePath and botFileSecret.`);
    console.error(`\n - See https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot file its use and bot configuration.\n\n`);
    process.exit();
}

// For local development configuration as defined in .bot file
const DEV_ENVIRONMENT = 'development';

// bot name as defined in .bot file or from runtime
const BOT_CONFIGURATION = (process.env.NODE_ENV || DEV_ENVIRONMENT);

// Get bot endpoint configuration by service name
const endpointConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(BOT_CONFIGURATION);

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about .bot file its use and bot configuration .
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.microsoftAppID,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.microsoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
    // Clear out state
    await conversationState.delete(context);
};

// Define a state store for your bot.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-state to learn more about using MemoryStorage.
// A bot requires a state store to persist the dialog and user state between messages.
let conversationState, userState;

// For local development, in-memory storage is used.
// CAUTION: The Memory Storage used here is for local bot debugging only. When the bot
// is restarted, anything stored in memory will be gone.
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

// CAUTION: You must ensure your product environment has the NODE_ENV set
//          to use the Azure Blob storage or Azure Cosmos DB providers.

// Add botbuilder-azure when using any Azure services.
// const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');
// // Get service configuration
// const blobStorageConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(STORAGE_CONFIGURATION_ID);
// const blobStorage = new BlobStorage({
//     containerName: (blobStorageConfig.container || DEFAULT_BOT_CONTAINER),
//     storageAccountOrConnectionString: blobStorageConfig.connectionString,
// });
// conversationState = new ConversationState(blobStorage);
// userState = new UserState(blobStorage);

// Create the main dialog.
let bot;
try {
    bot = new BasicBot(conversationState, userState, botConfig);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`[botInitializationError]: ${ err }`);
    process.exit();
}

// Create HTTP server
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo talk to your bot, open dev-hr-app.bot file in the Emulator`);
});

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.onTurn(turnContext);
    });
});
```

Could somebody, please, point me to the solution for this issue?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Consider printing the error in the try .. catch block where you are loading the Bot Configuration in index.js. Something like `console.error(err)`. It could be that you have an different kind of error, than what is described in the prewritten error message.

Comment: It looks like you commented out the line where you configure the dotenv object in your index.js file - seven lines down from the top. Uncomment that line and try running your code again.  `const env = require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});`

Comment: @tdurnford that was a line I have added manually after reading through the documentation and forums on the internet. Commented or uncommented -  the result is still the same. Thank you!

Comment: @AlgorithmicCanary, added
`} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
....
{`
now getting this error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 281
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .bot file, a comma is missing between your 2 items in your `services` array. Should be like the following:

```
{
    "name": "dev-hr-app",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "name": "development",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
            "appId": "",
            "appPassword": "",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "type": "luis",
            "name": "dev-hr-app",
            "appId": "<ID>", <- deleted
            "version": "0.1",
            "authoringKey": "<Key>", <- deleted
            "subscriptionKey": "<Key>", <- deleted
            "region": "westus",
            "id": "206"
        }
    ],
    "padlock": "",
    "version": "2.0"
}
```